# Android bluetooth earphones not working Nogut 7.0 and later versions

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-7.0-nougat

I am using following code for connecting bluetooth

```
    public void startBluetooth() {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.startBluetoothSco();
    }

    public void stopBluetooth() {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.stopBluetoothSco();
    }
```

I am using this to record audio using bluetooth mic and also listen parallel audio within bluetooth earphones.
It is working fine on every OS version except Nogut and Oreo.

I am using media recorder as following

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
startBluetooth();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```